# SonarQube Eclipse integration throwing NoSuchMethodError on Synchronize Issues

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

My maven project is properly associated with the project on our Sonar server. When I try to use the Eclipse "Analyze Project" option, it brings up a Problem Occurred window with

"'Synchronize issues' has encountered a problem.

An internal error occurred during: "Synchronize issues".

The details dropdown has

> An internal error occurred during: "Synchronize issues".
>   org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

If I look in the Eclipse log, I see

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-07-13 14:07:23.716
>   !MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Synchronize issues".
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>       at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyseProjectJob.(AnalyseProjectJob.java:88)
>       at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.scheduleIncrementalAnalysis(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:100)
>       at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.run(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Strangely enough, I installed the plugin on another machine today and Analyze Project works fine. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: This is usually caused by dependency issue after updating plugin several times. Please try to remove all outdated <eclipse install dir>/plugins/org.sonar.ide.* and restart Eclipse with -clean command line parameter.

Comment: My Installation Details shows that I have 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE installed, but I have no org.sonar* in either my <eclipse install>/plugins or <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins.

Comment: I recently updated the plugin and this issue is resolved.